# Why does tensor flow return NaN when running variables after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I can't really understand why this is not working, basically I'm trying to retrieve values for m and q just to print them but I always get [nan, nan]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=()), dtype=tf.float32)
q = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=()), dtype=tf.float32)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = m * X + q

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
gdescent = optimizer.minimize(cost)

train, test = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in ["train.csv", "test.csv"]]

if False:  # Scatter training points
    plt.scatter(train['x'], train['y'], s=1)
    plt.show()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    _, m, q = sess.run([gdescent, m, q], feed_dict={X: train['x'].values, y: train['y'].values})
    print(m, q)
```

train.csv and test.csv are both files with a header line and two columns of values, x and y

First 10 lines of train.csv

```
x,y
24,21.54945196
50,47.46446305
15,17.21865634
38,36.58639803
87,87.28898389
36,32.46387493
12,10.78089683
81,80.7633986
25,24.61215147
```

Comment: Provide the `train.csv` as well

Comment: Done, look at the edit

Comment: The data matters. I ran the code with *this* csv file and never got a NaN. Copying the rows didn't change it as well.

Comment: Same! But why is that? I got the files from here https://www.kaggle.com/andonians/random-linear-regression

Comment: Ok got it, line 215 is missing a value, what a rookie mistake XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the error was that train.csv was missing the y value at line 215